# Android Studio 3.3.2 Stuck at Project Setup:reading from cache

Tags: android, android-studio

I recently installed the new version of android studio, but every time I reopen a project, the gradle configuration automatically tries syncing to the project, which is perfectly normal.

However, the sync never completes and is stuck at

> Project Setup: reading from cache.

Someone know how can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I have also found AS to be pretty slow, it just stops/hangs and then resumes. This might not solve the problem completely but can be tried. Destroy the .gradle folder and .idea folder (extreme case destroy the main .gradle folder on you computer home directory). Once that is done, re-import the project in AS. These directories maintain local cache data, which might be causing these issues.

Comment: How's this different from invalidating cache + restarting?

Comment: Invalidate cache only clears the .idea as far as I know.

Answer (score 0):

According to [known_issues_with_the_android_gradle_plugin](https://developer.android.com/studio/known-issues#known_issues_with_the_android_gradle_plugin):

> Configuration on demand with Gradle 4.6 and above: If you're using Android Gradle Plugin 3.0.x or 3.1.x with Gradle 4.6 and above, you should disable configuration on demand to avoid some unpredictable build errors. (If you are using Android Gradle Plugin 3.2.0 or higher, you do not need to take any action to disable configuration on demand.)

Disable configuration on demand in your `gradle.properties` file as shown below:

```
org.gradle.configureondemand=false
```

Also, note that **Gradle** caches directories

- On **macOS**/**Linux**: `$HOME/.gradle/caches/`
- On **Windows**: `%USER_HOME%\.gradle/caches/`

Try to close your Android Studio and delete those directories then restart Android Studio.

More about build caches is here: [Android Studio Build Cache](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-cache)